# ListBox SelectionMode Single multiple select

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem

I'm having a rather strange problem while working with a `ListBox` on a `WPF` program.
I've defined my `ListBox` `SelectionMode` as `Single`, but it appear that even if visually I cannot select multiples items, it happens in the code.
As can be seen here :
[image: SelectionModeSingleWithMultipleSelected]

When trying to do a workaround, I tried to use the function UnselectAll, it rather strangly still leave an item selected :
[image: UnselectAllStillSelected]

And as a last gift, once multiple items have been selected, if I try to click on my unselected visualy, selected in the code, item my application crash with a System.ArgumentException (I suppose it tries to select my item, that's already selected in fact, so it crashes because of adding a perfect duplicate ?)
[image: ApplicationCrashOnListBoxClick]

I looked into [ListBox is selecting many items even in SelectionMode="Single"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843784/listbox-is-selecting-many-items-even-in-selectionmode-single) that had kindof the same problem, but in my case I cannot visually select multiples items, and my items are completly distinct so it doesn't really help.

I don't have any custom behavior on ListBox.Click that could mess with something ...

my `ListBox.ItemsSource` is bound to a list of Items.
I will decrement the value of a property of the selected Item when calling `useItem` on it, but it is still the same item (I don't recreate it/remove it then add it again)

Where is my problem coming from ?
How can I fix it ?

Comment: Is SelectedItems bound to anything in your xaml?

Comment: is it possible that something else is adding items to that list?

Comment: I'm modifying the selected item in the 'useItem' function (my item posses an int charge field that I decrease by 1). But I only modify the item, I do not create a new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, finally found the origin of my problem.

Having a custom Item, I had to redefine my Equals function.
I then had to redefine my `GetHashCode` function too, which I based on several of my properties, including the field I am decrementing ...
So when I would change the field, I would at the same time change my `HashCode` and I couldn't access my item anymore.

Changing my `GetHashCode` function to base it on an immutable field solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your `SelectionMode` is `Single`, you should not bind to `SelectedItems` as per [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2). Just use `SelectedItem`.

Comment: I don't.
My binding looks as follow :
`listItemSave = new BindingList<Item>(hero.backPack.getItems);`
`listBoxBackPackItem.ItemsSource = this.listItemSave;`

I never use `SelectedItems`, it is only visible on the `Watch`, I only use `SelectedItem` in the code.

edit : just seen that I missunderstood a previous comment, thinking it was asking if I had my listItems (my ItemsSource) bound, my mistake.
I'm not sure I can edit my previous comment to correct my mistake.

Comment: Ok, good. How do you notice the issue (except when debugging)? Is there more than one item shown as selected in the UI? Is the `SelectedItem` the wrong item? What does you `Food` class look like?

Comment: The SelectedItem is the first item in SelectedItems, it means if I try to select another Item and act on it, it will still try the action on the first item.
And then when I try to select my first item again (so he's not selected visually but is present in my SelectedItems) my application will then crash as per my third screenshot.

Comment: My food class contains a string (name) and an int (nbCharges).
In my function I will decrement the nbCharges.
In case you'd need it the code can be found in it's entirety here https://github.com/Belterius/LDVELH/tree/WPFBranch/LDVELH_WPF

The related files would be mainwindow.xaml.cs, Item.cs and EventHandler.cs

Comment: I can't pinpoint the exact problem, but I noticed that you don't use `Binding` at least for the `ItemsSource` property and pretty much everything is set in the code behind. I would suggest refactoring a bit: start using MVVM-pattern, it will make your life with WPF easier.

Comment: I thought that setting my ItemsSource = List was equivalent to binding, I'll try to change things and see if it gets better.
As for refactoring, I agree, I discovered too late into my project the recommended implementation, so I was planning on having everything working and then trying to refactor, but I still have some trouble with the concept so I'm learning on other smaller sample project before refactoring this one.